# Python Script to create a list of video titles of a YouTube playlist containing more than 100 videos

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, youtube

I am using code provided below to create a list containing titles of videos in a public YouTube playlist. It works well for playlists containing less than 100 videos. For playlists containing more than 100 videos, titles of first 100 videos in the playlist will be added to the list. I think reason behind this behaviour is because when we load the same page in browser, first 100 videos are loaded. Remaining videos are loaded as you scroll down the page. Is there any way to get titles of all videos from a playlist?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRdD1c6QbAqJn0606RlOR6T3yUqFWKwmX"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text,'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'pl-video yt-uix-tile'})
titles = []
for video in res:
    titles.append(video.get('data-title'))
```

Comment: I can't tell what your real goal is here, but if it just to download a complete playlist, do  you know about the python-based tool/utility `youtube-dl` ? It can download a single vid, or a playlist. It has options to randomize the download so you don't show up as a datahog to youTube.. HTH . Good luck.

Comment: I wanted to rename files by adding a number(serial in playlist) before every video file. I have already downloaded videos. Anyways thanks for telling about `youtube-dl`. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created following script with the help of inputs from [Abrogans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993022/8422208).

Also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/davidcairuz/b187bf657e1b1174f712224c1794ce5b) was helpful.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRdD1c6QbAqJn0606RlOR6T3yUqFWKwmX"
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.END)

innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

page_soup = bs(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
res = page_soup.find_all('span',{'class':'style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer'})

titles = []
for video in res:
    if video.get('title') != None:
        titles.append((video.get('title')))

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen correctly only the first 100 Videos are loaded. When the user scrolls down [**ajax calls**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) are made to load the additional videos.

The easiest, but also most heavywheigt option to reproduce the ajax
   calls is to use **selenium webdriver**. You can find the official
   python documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thanks for giving a push in the right direction. I tried using selenium webdriver and I succeeded in creating a list containing all videos' titles from a playlist even if it contains more than 100 videos.